# Getting error on gettext from edittext?

Tags: android, string, gettext

I'm making a simple application that changes images when a certain string is typed in a dialog box but when I try to get the string from edit text(in the dialog) the application stops and gives an error

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

 ImageView im;

 final Context context = this;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.start); 
      im = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    final MediaPlayer mp  = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.hey);
    final Button chat = (Button) findViewById(R.id.chat);

    chat.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
             dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog);
             dialog.setTitle("Friendly Chat");
             TextView col = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.color);
             col.setText("Which is your favorite color? ");



            Button subb = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.sub);
            subb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    EditText  edt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ans);
                    String S = edt.getText().toString();
                    if (S.equals("blue")){
                        im.setImageResource(R.drawable.a1b);
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "I also love blue", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }else if(S.equals("red")){
                        im.setImageResource(R.drawable.a1r);
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "I also love red", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }else if (S.equals("yellow")){
                        im.setImageResource(R.drawable.a1y);
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "I also love yellow", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }else if (S.equals("green")){
                        im.setImageResource(R.drawable.a1g);
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "I also love green", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }else if (S.equals("black")){
                        im.setImageResource(R.drawable.a1bl);
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "I also love black", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }else if (S.equals("white")){
                        im.setImageResource(R.drawable.a1wh);
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "I also love white", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }else if (S.equals("orange")){
                        im.setImageResource(R.drawable.a1o);
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "I also love orange", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }else if (S.equals("brown")){
                        im.setImageResource(R.drawable.a1br);
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "I also love brown", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }else if (S.equals("silver")){
                        im.setImageResource(R.drawable.a1s);
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "I also love silver", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }else if (S.equals("purple")){
                        im.setImageResource(R.drawable.a1p);
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "I also love purple", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }else{
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Color does not exist please clearify i.e black,blue or green etc", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                      dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
            dialog.show();
        }
    });
    im.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.anim);
    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            AnimationDrawable anim 
            = (AnimationDrawable) im.getBackground();

                anim.stop();
                anim.start();
                mp.start();


        }
    });

}}
```

and my layout is

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="pocketfriend.foryou.MainActivity"
 android:background="@drawable/bg"
>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/start"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="130dp"
    android:text="Start" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="300dp"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/chat"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Chat" />
```

dialog.xml is

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/ans"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:capitalize="none"
    android:layout_below="@+id/color"
    android:ems="10" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/color"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="23dp"
     />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/sub"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/ans"
    android:text="Submit" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

my log cat is showing

```
  06-08 19:41:40.792: E/AndroidRuntime(9945): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
  06-08 19:41:40.792: E/AndroidRuntime(9945): java.lang.NullPointerException
    06-08 19:41:40.792: E/AndroidRuntime(9945):     at    pocketfriend.foryou.MainActivity$1$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:52)
    06-08 19:41:40.792: E/AndroidRuntime(9945):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4091)
    06-08 19:41:40.792: E/AndroidRuntime(9945):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17072)
    06-08 19:41:40.792: E/AndroidRuntime(9945):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
    06-08 19:41:40.792: E/AndroidRuntime(9945):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    06-08 19:41:40.792: E/AndroidRuntime(9945):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
    06-08 19:41:40.792: E/AndroidRuntime(9945):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5026)
    06-08 19:41:40.792: E/AndroidRuntime(9945):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    06-08 19:41:40.792: E/AndroidRuntime(9945):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    06-08 19:41:40.792: E/AndroidRuntime(9945):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:821)
    06-08 19:41:40.792: E/AndroidRuntime(9945):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:584)
    06-08 19:41:40.792: E/AndroidRuntime(9945):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Could you provide the logcat output for the error?

Comment: done I've provided the log cat ! please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to access the EditText from the wrong view. The EditText exists in the dialog, not the main activity's context.

Replace:

```
EditText  edt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ans);
```

with:

```
EditText  edt = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.ans);
```